# Compiling Glibc

Tags: compilation, header, include, glibc

I'm attempting to compile and package Glibc for what may eventually become my own Linux distribution. --with-headers=directory allows me to tell Glibc that the kernel headers are in a different place. But how do I tell Glibc to put it's own headers in a non standard location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you run `./configure --help`, it'll show many flags to control various install paths.  for headers, use `--includedir=/some/other/path`.